# VBA: Code for creating subfolders and folders not working

Tags: vba

I got this code from an online source and cant figure out what I have to change, for it to work, the folders are not being created in the desired location and I am unaware of where they are be created if any where?

Within the excel I have 3 command buttons, one to save the file to a specified location, one to email it to a collegue and lastly the command button which I am having issue with. Ill include images below.

And is it possible to cause a chain reaction between the codes, that once one is completed then the other will begin, as I can get them to work as they are on there own atm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMSSB.png)

Comment: please paste the code here as text. it's very [hard to debug via picture](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1):

Mkdir can only create a single directory. You are trying to make two by supplying  "9999 William Cox ltd\BRAKEL".

Make "9999 William Cox ltd" first, then make its child directories.

Here is some code that will generate all of the sub directories via a loop:

**Add these functions to your code module:**

```
Private Function makeDir(parentDir As String, childDir As String) As String
    'Checks if supplied directory name exists in current path, if not then create.
    childDir = parentDir & _
        IIf(Left(childDir, 1) = "\", "", "\") & _
        childDir & _
        IIf(Right(childDir, 1) = "\", "", "\")

    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir childDir
    On Error GoTo 0

    makeDir = childDir
End Function

Public Sub makePath(parentDir As String, childPath As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim subDirs As Variant
    Dim newdir As String
    Dim fPath As String

    fPath = parentDir
    subDirs = Split(childPath, "\")

    For i = 0 To UBound(subDirs)

        newdir = subDirs(i)
        fPath = makeDir(fPath, newdir)

    Next i

End Sub
```

**Then replace this:**

```
MkDir ("T:\Estimating\William Cox Project Enquiries 2018\" & fPath)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
End If
```

**With this:**

```
makePath "T:\Estimating\William Cox Project Enquiries 2018\", fpath
```

You should also remove `On Error Resume Next` so that you can catch any other errors - Another of which might be in your path (per the screenshot) which has "T:\Estimating" twice at the beginning.